# What is this limit equal to? $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac{f(1)}{2} + ... + \frac{f(n)}{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

$f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow R$ given by $f(x)=(x+1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac{f(1)}{2} + \frac{f(2)}{3} + ... + \frac{f(n)}{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

I have calculed the derivative and established that the function is monotonically decreasing, and I tried to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac{f(1)}{2} + \frac{f(1)}{3} + ... + \frac{f(1)}{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac{f(n)}{2} + \frac{f(n)}{3} + ... + \frac{f(n)}{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ to maybe pin the results   between  two other limits but I have not been successful

Comment: Would you be able to explain us what you did so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Note that $$\frac{f(1)}{2} + \frac{f(2)}{3} +\cdots+ \frac{f(n)}{n+1}=\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(\dfrac32\right)+\cdots+\ln\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)$$ and $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$ for any $a, b$ positive reals.